# mysql db records visibility (design and select help)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i need to design a mysql db with users and projects. besides other infos, the projects table holds info on wether the project is

- visible to all users
- visible to users located in one or more geographical regions
- visible only to selected users

for example a project can be visible to all users located in region 1, 5 and 8, but also to n selected users not located in region 1, 5 and 8.

the geographical region of a user is stored in the user table (for example region:4)

my question is where to store the project visibility, project regions and selected users and how to show (select) all relevant projects to a user.

i need to show the user a list of all projects

- that are visible to all users
- that are visible to the user because of his region
- that are visible to the user because he is selected to see the project

any help would he highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the table structure. Note that based on your MySQL version you may need to change the type=INNODB to ENGINE=INNODB:

```
drop table if exists prjusers;

drop table if exists proj_users;

drop table if exists project_regions;

drop table if exists projects;

drop table if exists regions;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: prjusers                                              */
/*==============================================================*/
create table prjusers
(
   id_prjuser           int not null auto_increment,
   id_region            int not null,
   user_name            varchar(100) not null,
   primary key (id_prjuser)
)
type = InnoDB;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: proj_users                                            */
/*==============================================================*/
create table proj_users
(
   id_proj_user         int not null auto_increment,
   id_prjuser           int not null,
   id_project           int not null,
   primary key (id_proj_user)
)
type = InnoDB;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: project_regions                                       */
/*==============================================================*/
create table project_regions
(
   id_project_region    int not null auto_increment,
   id_project           int not null,
   id_region            int not null,
   primary key (id_project_region)
)
type = InnoDB;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: projects                                              */
/*==============================================================*/
create table projects
(
   id_project           int not null auto_increment,
   prj_code             varchar(100) not null,
   global_project       char(1) not null,
   primary key (id_project)
)
type = InnoDB;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: regions                                               */
/*==============================================================*/
create table regions
(
   id_region            int not null auto_increment,
   region_name          varchar(100) not null,
   primary key (id_region)
)
type = InnoDB;

alter table prjusers add constraint FK_relationship_12 foreign key (id_region)
      references regions (id_region) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table proj_users add constraint FK_relationship_10 foreign key (id_prjuser)
      references prjusers (id_prjuser) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table proj_users add constraint FK_relationship_11 foreign key (id_project)
      references projects (id_project) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table project_regions add constraint FK_relationship_8 foreign key (id_project)
      references projects (id_project) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table project_regions add constraint FK_relationship_9 foreign key (id_region)
      references regions (id_region) on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

**The select statement:**

```
select id_project, prj_code from projects where global_project='Y'
UNION
select projects.id_project, projects.prj_code 
from projects join project_regions on projects.id_project = project_regions.id_project 
join prjusers on prjusers.id_region = project_regions.id_region
where prjusers.id_prjuser = {$_SESSION['id_prjuser']}
UNION
select projects.id_project, projects.prj_code 
from projects join proj_users on projects.id_project = proj_users.id_project
where proj_users.id_prjuser = {$_SESSION['id_prjuser']}
```

The above will do 3 UNIONS and come up with the project ID and project codes that are global (1), that fall in the region of the logged in user whose ID is kept in a session variable (2) and all projects that are explicitly assigned to that user.

Answer (score 0):

USER --------* USER_PROJECT* ----- PROJECT -------*REGION_PROJECT*-----REGION---* USER

USER and PROJECT are many-to-many related with a mapping table USER_PROJECT

USER and REGION are many-to-one related

PROJECT and REGION are many-to-many related with a mapping table REGION_PROJECT

This comments is meant to complement @somnath's answer.I couldn't add this relationship in the comments.
@somnath, I hope my answers explains the relationship between the tables you designed  correctly.